# .NET Core Subdomain addresses with areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my current Startup.cs.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

});
```

This results in this example url:

> www.locahost.com:9988/Directory/Users/Create

Is there any way for me to keep using the areas for certain roles or paths and for the other roles, redirect them to a subdomain built from their name? Something like what Shopify does?

Comment: You could use a url rewriting rule to map the subdomain to a Asp.Net friendly url. Then your application doesn't need any special knowledge of how it is hosted.

Comment: Hi @Steve , do you have any examples of this? I have tried searching around but there are plenty of old multi tenant tutorials that aren't really helpful.

Comment: O have followed this recentky. Specifically the canonical hostnames https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#canonical     if you search IIS ARR, Url Rewrite rules you will find some useful guides